# Did I write this query correct?

Tags: sql

Write a query to show the **student’s fname, lname, courseId, CourseName, and Grade of students** `R# = R0000123 and CourseId = 11111`

**Table Course:**

```
CourseId    SubjectId   Course_Name Title   numOfCredit
11111   CSET    3200    Client Server Architecture  3
11112   CSET    1200    GUI Programming 3
```

**Table Students**

```
R_Num   fName   MI  lName   Email
R0000123    Jacob   R   Smith   Jacob.smith@utoledo.edu
R0000124    Frank   K   Jones   Frank.jones@utoledo.edu
```

**Table Grade**

```
R_Num   CourseId    Grade
R0000123    11111   A
R0000123    11112   B
```

I wrote :

```
SELECT fName, lName, CourseId, CourseName, Grade
FROM Table Course, Table Students, Table Grade
WHERE R Num = R0000123 AND CourseId = 11111
```

Comment: What happened when you ran the query? Did it match the expected output?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Where are the join conditions between the tables?

Comment: This question is getting better than the previous ones. lol. Study JOINs. I'm sure you will get there in no time: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)

Comment: So I just need to write JOIN between each table sets in the FROM row

Comment: Haven't you just posted this exact question an hour ago?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT B.FNAME, B.LNAME, A.COURSEID, C.COURSE_NAME, A.GRADE

FROM TABLE GRADE A 

INNER JOIN TABLE STUDENTS B ON A.R_NUM=B.R_NUM

INNER JOIN TABLE COURSE C ON A.COURSEID=C.COURSEID

WHERE A.R_NUM='0000123' AND A.COURSEID='11111'
```